# db2 SQL XMLQUERY LOOP

Tags: sql, xml, select, db2

```
<phone type="work">905-555-7258</phone>
<phone type="home">416-555-2937</phone>
<phone type="cell">905-555-8743</phone>
<phone type="cottage">613-555-3278</phone>
...

SELECT
        XMLCAST(XMLQUERY    ('$d/customerinfo/phone[n]/@type'
                        PASSING INFO AS "d") as VARCHAR(128)) type,
        XMLCAST(XMLQUERY    ('$d/customerinfo/phone[n]'
                        PASSING INFO AS "d") as VARCHAR(128)) number
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

How can i select n phone nummbers? I am thinking about something like a for loop (java), but I cant find a way to do that in SQL for DB2.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add how many documents you have and the expected output? It should be doable by combining SQL and XQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine CTE with ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() N,X.*
FROM XMLTABLE ('$cust/customerinfo/phone' PASSING 
XMLPARSE(CLOB('<customerinfo Cid="1003">
  <name>Robert Shoemaker</name>
    <addr country="Canada">
    <street>1596 Baseline</street>
    <city>Aurora</city>
    <prov-state>Ontario</prov-state>
    <pcode-zip>N8X 7F8</pcode-zip>
  </addr>
  <phone type="work">905-555-7258</phone>
  <phone type="home">416-555-2937</phone>
  <phone type="cell">905-555-8743</phone>
  <phone type="cottage">613-555-3278</phone>
</customerinfo>')) as "cust"
   COLUMNS 
   "PHONETYPE" CHAR(30) PATH '@type',
   "PHONENUM" CHAR(15) PATH '.'
  ) as X
) AS phones
WHERE 
N=4
```

Comment: No authorized routine named "XMLPARSE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.19.26 SQL Code: -440, SQL State: 42884